# Pulling records out of JSON API response and putting them into Delta Table

Tags: json, api, databricks

I have received a JSON response object from an API call and I've stored that in my datalake as a JSON. Im now trying to read in that object into Databricks and save the records from the response "result" key's value array as a delta table. The JSON Object structure looks like this:

```
{
    "result":
        [{*record_1*}, {*record_2*}, ..., {*record_n*}],
    "error":
            {
            "detail":"",
            "message":""
            },
    "status":""
}

where {*record_1*} translates to { "field1":"value1", "field2":"value2" , "fieldN":"valueN" }
```

The record {} object is a collection of comma separated key/value pairs as the example above. What Im trying to achieve is to parse/open the "result" value pair and store these as a table of data for analysis, then automate that flow so new records from the new API call can be amended to this Delta file.

Where Im struggling is how to open/read the "record" fields data and save the data into a structured Delta table - when exploring this I either get a null for the values in the "result", "error" and "status" column or I can only read in a single record from the results array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.